# how to declare css style for child element in style.ts

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm developing a page with multiple div elements, I'm using **{classes.parent}**
and **{classes.child}** , I want to apply CSS to child class based on the parent className,  below format I'm using can anyone help on this, please

app.js

```
<div className={classes.parent}>
 <h5>Parent Data</h5>
 <div className={classes.child}>Child Data</div>
</div>
```

style.ts

```
parent: {
    backgroundColor: "blue",
    color: "white",
    padding: "10px 20px",
'& child'{
  color: "yellow",
  }
},
```

Comment: Don't nest `child` inside the `parent`.

Comment: i want nest child for theming purpose @medi

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do nesting then:

```
parent: {
    backgroundColor: "blue",
    color: "white",
    padding: "10px 20px",
'& $child'{
  color: "yellow",
  }
},
```

Comment: thank you very much for your answer can't we generate JSS for the child class?

Comment: the className generated by JSS is dynamic and may change on each render. i updated the answer.

Comment: make sure to used `className={classes.child}` for class naming.

Comment: I have checked even though it's not working

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/amazing-thunder-lcnlw?file=/src/App.tsx , you can check this link